# Plotting a charge function

Tags: matlab

I feel very frustrated with MATLAB because I'm just trying to plot a function and keep receiving this error:

> Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

There goes my code:

```
file charge.m
function [q]=charge(t)
G=66;
R=24.7;
L=2.74;
C=0.000251;
P1=-0.5*(R/L)*t;
P2=t*sqrt(1/(L*C)-(R^2)/(4*L^2));
q=G*exp(P1)*cos(P2);
```

and my main function

main.m

```
x=(0:0.001:1);
y=charge(x.)
plot(x,y)
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep searching and searching about how to do this and I'm still blank about it.

Comment: "Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket."
Just a shot in the dark here but are you missing semicolons from these two lines?

y=charge(x.) 
plot(x,y)

(Edit: I don't know matlab or even why I'm reading this, just a guess)

Comment: Please work on your wording.

Comment: semi-colons have nothing to do with any error here.

Comment: Why is the dot here, `y=charge(x.)` ? It can cause the problem. On which line the error is? EDIT- A better guess is the parenthesis here- `x=(0:0.001:1);`, you should remove it

Comment: Adiel if I try to use only x I get the error "Inner matrix dimensions must agree"

Comment: Adiel I still get the same error even if I remove parentheses

Comment: You have an extra dot as pointed by Adiel and a missing dot here: `q=G*exp(P1).*cos(P2);`

Comment: The error "Inner matrix dimensions must agree" is due to wrong multiplication in the last line

Comment: I'm getting confused... Where and why should I use the dot?

Comment: As in @SardarUsama's comment... Remove the dot here- `(x.)`, and add a dot there.

Comment: Yes I saw it but I want to know why use the dot there and not in x

Comment: You cannot just randomly put things and expect them to work. Please read the documentation of what different operators and functions do

Comment: In `x` it has no meaning. In the `exp.*cos` that's because vectors multiplication rules

Comment: @GrangerObliviate the dot is used for element by element multiplication.

Comment: And where can I read that? Do you realize how frustrating MATLAB is when you are using it for the first time? There are so many manuals, useless videos and etc.

Comment: Here for example https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html

Comment: Adiel I think I'm understanding now. I only use x in P1 and P2 and I'm just multiplying it by constants. When I multiply a function that depends on x, as is the exponential is where I need the dot. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, we all had to learn MATLAB. When I was learning, there weren't nearly as many manuals, there was no online documentation, and there were no "useless" videos. I had to learn everything the hard way. You have it easy, and still you complain... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a dot in the last line of the function definition for element by element multiplication.

```
function [q]=charge(t)
G=66;
R=24.7;
L=2.74;
C=0.000251;
P1=-0.5*(R/L)*t;
P2=t*sqrt(1/(L*C)-(R^2)/(4*L^2));
q=G*exp(P1).*cos(P2); % element by element multiplication so dot is introduced

x=(0:0.001:1);
y=charge(x)
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you Aditya! As I said above "I think I'm understanding now. I only use x in P1 and P2 and I'm just multiplying it by constants. When I multiply a function that depends on x, as is the exponential is where I need the dot."

Comment: That's true because your function is a vector so you need the dot. Also, you can multiply vectors of the same length. You got it !!

Comment: `y=charge(x.)` is not valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Yes get rid of the dot there.